# Swift UIViewController is missing in the library

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, user-interface

Why can't I find UIViewController in the library when I build an app in the SwiftUI in the interface builder instead of storyboard??

I appreciate your comments,

Comment: `UIViewController` is not part of SwiftUI. If you want to use it, don't use SwiftUI.

Comment: Ok! But what can I do in this case to be able to add more UIViewController??

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit

Comment: SwiftUI is a different framework with a fairly different paradigm compared to UIKit; if you're working in SwiftUI and thinking *how can I add more view controllers?* you might need to change the way you're thinking about your task.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments and I defintly appreciate your help 

Answer (score 1):

`UIViewController` is part of `UIKit` not `SwiftUI`. If you want to use one in `SwiftUI` you need to wrap it in `UIViewControllerRepresentable`.

On the other hand, if you want to use a `SwiftUI` View in `UIKit`, you need to wrap it an a `UIHostingController`.

Comment: Ok! Now I understand that. Well! The reason why I wanted to use Swift UI is because it's the new update and it doesn't require to much coding just to add an element or compunent in the Xcode "interface builder" But my other question is it possible to create a new file for storyboard in the Swift UI interface builder?? Because I heard you can build an app using UIkit elements while working in Swift UI.

Comment: The simple answer is "Yes".